# Connect to Google API within my Organization

Tags: python, google-api

I am trying to extract data from a Google Sheets on a Shared Google Drive within my organization using Python. I have the following code that works when I connect to my personal Google Drive, but not within the Organization. The reason being is that I have to share the Google Sheets with my Service Account, but within the Shared Drive, I get an error stating that I am not allowed to share the Sheets outside of my organization (it's counting my Service Account as outside of the org).

How would I workaround this?

```
def create_credentials():       
    credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            json_key,
            scopes=scopes)
    return gspread.authorize(credentials)

def read_spreadsheet(sample_spreadsheet_id, tab_index):    
    gc = create_credentials()
    gc = gc.open_by_key(sample_spreadsheet_id)
    values = gc.get_worksheet(tab_index).get_all_values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(values)
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)         
    return df

df_grade = read_spreadsheet(sheet_id, 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Service accounts are used behind the user.

- Add the scopes needed for the script from Google Admin Console. (Use
  service account ID)
- Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation
- Download the service account private key in JSON.

> ```
> var JSON_user = {
>   "private_key": "your private key",
>   "client_email": "your client email"
>    };
>
>   function getOAuthService(userId) {
>   return OAuth2.createService("Service Account")
>   .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
>   .setPrivateKey(JSON_user.private_key)
>   .setIssuer(JSON_user.client_email)
>   .setSubject(userId)
>   .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())
>   .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
>   .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive')
>   .setParam('approval_prompt', 'auto');
>    }
> ```

Now you can impersonate a user like this:

```
var service = getOAuthService("user email to impersonate");
```

Comment: Where does this go? Under my create credentials function? Also, is this Python? It looks like js